# Custom MVC Framework using php

Tags: php, frameworks, relative-path

I am working on my custom php MVC Framework.
I have setup all the things, everything's working fine but I have some jQuery plugins called rath which is basically for rating system.

In the rath plugin there is a path to ratings icons which is used to show the ratings. But the images do not load up on the page because there is static path like: images/raty-images/ in the raty plugin.

Comment: It would help if you posted some code, so we can see what is going on.  I could say "replace the static path with a base path and a variable representing the file name"  but it's not really that helpful is it...

Comment: Ok. I added the base path and the problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a symlink on server to point /images/raty-images/ to the actual path of where images are located or moves the images to wherever it thinks its supposed to be. You can use any browser console to see where its pointing to.